# Size of record pointer in InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to put on a scale redundant attributes and performance gain. Although storing redundant information causes many anomalies, I am solely focusing on the size of a redundant attribute vs. storing a pointer (or reference) to another tuple in different table.

So what is the size of pointer to a tuple in InnoDB Mysql systems? I found that MyISAM uses 6 bytes. Is it the same for InnoDB? For reference, 6 bytes makes storing 3 SMALLINTs (2 bytes each) in a separate table pointless in terms of storage. Perhaps an equivalent question would be: what is the size of a record address?

Comment: Why so complicated?  Just use a Foreign Key for your "reference".  The RDBMS can use that information to optimize.  The row reference? not so much.  Oh..what should happen when you remove the references row?

Comment: @MichaelKutz Thanks for stopping by. I am not sure if my question was clear enough. My question is about the size - in bytes - of the pointer (reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MyISAM *defaults* to 6 bytes for a data pointer in an index.  And defaults to 5 bytes for index pointers.  The "6" you are referring to is a byte offset from the .MYI file into the .MYD file.  That is not necessarily relevant to the rest of your question.

InnoDB is much more complex.  It does not use pointers, only columns.

The data is stored in a BTree that is ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (Actually a B+Tree.)

A secondary index is stored in a separate BTree that has the PK in each node record.

FKs are simply the indicated column(s), and are used to do a lookup in a suitable index in the other table.

```
id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

takes 1 byte, *plus some overhead*

```
id VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8mb4 PRIMARY KEY,
stuff1 VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8mb4,
stuff2 VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8mb4,
INDEX(stuff1, stuff2)
```

This last secondary index takes up to 3*(2+255)*4+? bytes --

- 3 columns (stuff1, stuff2, id)
- 2 -- length
- 255 -- max length in *characters* for utf8mb4
- 4 -- max bytes/character in utf8mb4
- +? -- There is overhead; this varies.

Back to "pointers".  There are some "pointers" at lower levels:

- 4 byte block pointer (16KB blocks), hence a limit of 64TB on table size.
- 20 byte pointer to overflow data (used to point to the 'rest' of a large `TEXT` or `BLOB`.
- Some 1-byte and 2-byte lengths or pointers inside a block.
- ? bytes for a transaction id.  (See MVCC, etc)

As a Rule of Thumb, an InnoDB table takes 2-3 times the disk space as the equivalent MyISAM table.

> So what is the size of pointer to a tuple in InnoDB Mysql systems?

- If `TINYINT UNSIGNED` suffices (up to 255 items in the other table), then think of it as 1 byte in each table, plus 1 byte for each secondary key in the target table.
- `INT` is often used (with a usually more-than-adequate 2-billion limit), think of it as 4 bytes each.

Perhaps a more important question is whether to have a 'surrogate' (`AUTO_INCREMENT`) id on a table.  Count the number of references in this table and from other tables to judge its bulk.  And use the smallest flavor of `INT` that will be safe.

That brings up "burning" of ids.  In almost all cases, `INSERT` (and its variants) will *first* allocate the auto_inc ids that it *might* need.  If it does not use them all (eg for `INSERT IGNORE`), the ids are lost (burned).  This can lead to using up, say, `TINYINT` much faster than anticipated.  For bulk normalization, I provide this technique:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I must admit.. I don't get what you mean by `InnoDB is much more complex. It does not use pointers, only columns.`

`A secondary index is stored in a separate BTree that has the PK in each node record.` I haven't heard before that a secondary (any non primary) index also contains the value primary key. You mean non-leaf nodes, right?

Comment: `FKs are simply the indicated column(s), and are used to do a lookup in a suitable index in the other table. ` If I get this correctly.. FK column only points to original PK column to do a constraint check on insert/update. Data in FK columns is repeated in the "new" relation and no space is saved.

Comment: @sanjihan - I'm pretty sure the PK column(s) are included throughout the secondary key's BTree, both leaf and non-leaf nodes.  In some situations, the Optimizer takes advantage of this when you use PK columns in a query's `WHERE` or `ORDER BY`, etc., and when the index is "covering".